# a:hover not overriding parent class

Tags: asp.net, css

I have an aspx page with a Masterpage containing a panel with a CssClass of `menutoolbar`.  Within that panel I am placing objects, in this case a linkbutton with a class of `SearchLink`.

In my Stylesheet, I am defining

```
.menutoolbar a:hover { color: red }

.Searchlink a:hover { color: yellow }
```

When I hover over the `Searchlink` link it is red!  This is not what I expect, the `Searchlink` specifically is defined as yellow, it looks like the parent container `menutoolbar` is overriding the color, reverse of what I would expect.

How can I make the hover effect yellow for `Searchlink`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a.Searchlink:hover { color: yellow }
```

Answer (score 3):

try doing:

```
.Searchlink a:hover { color: yellow!important; }
```

if the link class is "searchlink" you could try

```
a.Searchlink:hover { color: yellow; }
```

Comment: I would recommend against blindly using !important as a patch without fully understanding the problem

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can be more specific with the rule, e.g.

```
a.Searchlink:hover { color: yellow;}
```

Or something like that.